# ROLLUP with ORDER BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, rollup

I have a problem with query in mysql.
My Query:

```
SELECT year, person, SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM rentals
GROUP BY year, person WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY year DESC;
```

Gives me in response error like this:

> Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

I've read in other posts in StackOverFlow that in MySQL there can be a problem to use ROLLUP and ORDER BY in one query and I know that I can make this using subquery, but the point is that maybe one month ago I could make this query and yesterday the problem has started. Some days ago I turned on ONLY FULL GROUP BY mode, can it be the reason?
What can I do to be able to use the rollup with order by in one query as previously? I would like to make that I don't have to use subqueries because I know that there is some possibility to make this (like previously).

Comment: no the error comes not from there your version is incompatible in mysql 8 with fullgroupby this runs without a problem

Comment: Please run `SELECT version()` to categorically confirm which exact version of MySQL you have.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message comes from MySQL 5.7 or earlier. This construct you can use only in MySQL 8

> ```
> CREATE tABLE rentals(year int , person varchar(20), amount BIGINT )
> ```

> ```
> SELECT year, person, SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM rentals
> GROUP BY year, person WITH ROLLUP
> ORDER BY year DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> year | person | total_amount
> ---: | :----- | -----------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=188cc7e06961eb898fc8cf69c02f8353)*

IN MYSQL 5.7
You nned to run

> ```
> CREATE tABLE rentals(year int , person varchar(20), amount BIGINT )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM 
>
> (SELECT year, person,SUM(amount)
> FROM rentals
> GROUP BY year, person WITH ROLLUP) t1
> ORDER BY year DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> year | person | SUM(amount)
> ---: | :----- | ----------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=979fd8e0854758a0597c38dcfe454413)*

Comment: precisely since 8.0.12

Comment: I have read that I have version 8.0.26 - so this is the newest and in this version I can't use rollup with order by? And it was possible only in previous versions yes?

Comment: strange my Can do it and doesn't give that message, but i added a Version  that should run also and does the same